# package org.junit does not exist

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, classpath

I am using Jenkins, and using a Github repo as Source Code.

In the Build section, I am executing this as a Windows Batch command:

```
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin
cd \Users\harr\JenkinsServer\JenkinsTest\src
javac SimpleTest.java //Error is after this executes
java SimpleTest
```

I know it has something to do with classpath, but I am unsure how to solve this problem in jenkins.

Let me know if more information would be helpful.

Comment: Does this help ? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/EKSlqHglcsI

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you deploy the jekins server on linux platform, so you have to  install the jdk, tomcat and so on, set the env path as well. Then you don't have to execute `set path` before every build.

you can create a script and copy the command into it, then when jenkins performs the build task, it can execute the script. Refer to [the jenkins tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/index.htm) to learn about it.